PowerShell Script Fails to Fetch Azure DevOps Group Members with API (404 Error)
I’m trying to fetch the members of an Azure DevOps group using the Azure DevOps REST API and a PowerShell script. However, I keep encountering a 404 - Page not found error. Here's the error message:
The controller for path '/_apis/graph/groups/{GroupDescriptor}/members' was not found or does not implement IController.
404 - Page not found

What I Have Tried:
Script Details:
Here's the script I'm using:
# Parameters
$Organization = "my-organization-name" 
$GroupDescriptor = "vssgp...."  
$PAT = "my-personal-access-token"    

# API URL
$ApiUrl = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$Organization/_apis/graph/groups/$GroupDescriptor/members?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

# Headers
$Headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))"
}

# API Call
try {
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiUrl -Headers $Headers -Method Get
    $Response.value | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_.displayName
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error: $_"
}

Verified Group Descriptor:
I obtained the group descriptor using the GET /_apis/graph/groups API.
The descriptor matches the group I'm trying to query.
